# Find a set with empty interior and boundary equal to closure of $B^2$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ is empty and $\operatorname{Fr}(A)=\operatorname{Cl}(B^2)$

I'm not sure how to do this. If I define my set as $A=\{\text{$x$ in $B^2$ such that $x$ is rational}\}$ then the boundary of my set is $\operatorname{Cl}(B^2)$ and the interior is empty, but $A$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ and $B^2$?  I assume $\text{Cl}$ means closure.

Comment: @Tim: $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ is the frontier of $A$, otherwise known as the boundary of $A$.

Comment: Cl means closure

Comment: What about $B^2$?

Comment: The open Ball in R^3

Comment: @Greg: If $B^2$ is the open ball in $\Bbb R^3$, the problem is impossible: no subset of $\Bbb R^2$ has a boundary containing a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^3$. I think it far more likely that $B^2$ is the open ball in $\Bbb R^2$, in which case your $A$ works fine (assuming that by *rational* you mean an element of $\Bbb Q^2$).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Perhaps the problem has a typo.